# Java - Throwing exceptions from methods of an anonymous inner class that's declared inside a method

Tags: java, android-volley

I want to catch Volley Errors That occur in onResponse and onErrorResponse to throw them inside fetchAdmins Method.

```
public void fetchAdmins () throws JSONException, VolleyError {
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
            ...
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    try {
                        ...
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException error) {
// i want to throw this error in fetchAdmins.
                        throw new JSONException(error);
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
// + i want to throw this error in fetchAdmins.
            throw new VolleyError(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Please suggest me a way for achieving this in java if that's possible.

Comment: It looks to me like you want to throw exceptions from methods of an anonymous inner class. If that's correct, you might want to edit the title of your question. Maybe "Throwing exceptions from methods of an anonymous inner class?"

Comment: It also looks like you're trying initialize the JsonArrayRequest by typing all of the arguments directly into the parameter list, even when the parameters are quite complicated and involve code.  This is poor style imo.  Declare some private methods that return the proper values and put the code in those methods.  It'll be much cleaner to read.  I don't know if what you have now is considered good style in JavaScript, but I definitely wouldn't use it with Java.

Comment: Also I don't understand this: `catch (JSONException error) { throw new JSONException(error);` why are you catching an exception only to throw the exact same exception?  This makes no sense.  I think you need to explain in more detail what you are asking help with.  We can't help you if we don't understand the issue.

Comment: There appear to be some examples of catching errors with Volley/Gson on the Volley web page.  These examples are much clearer imo that what you are showing or trying to do.  Please take a look: https://google.github.io/volley/request-custom.html

Comment: Have you tried creating complete code that attempts this?  How did the compiler respond?